# Adding toolbar to a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

Am extending a `FragmentActivity` in a class which serves as my base activity where my other activities extend from. 
My issue is when I extend my other activities from my base activity, I loose toolbar functionality. How can I add this to my base activity so that my activities can inherit the toolbar? 
Any pointers?

Comment: do you mean actionBar ?

Comment: No. I know how to add action bar. I mean toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case fragments should have custom view of `ToolBar` you can implement `ToolBar` for each fragment separately.

add `ToolBar` into `fragment_layout` :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

find it in fragment :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        //set toolbar appearance
        toolbar.setBackground(R.color.material_blue_grey_800);

        //for crate home button
        ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

menu listener could be created two ways:

1.override `onOptionsItemSelected` in your fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

2.set listener for toolbar when create it in `onCreateView`():

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return false;
            }
});
```

Comment: You mean I should extend Fragments instead of extending FragmentActivity for my base activity??

Comment: Ya u can try this out

Comment: It won't work because fragments require an activity to be attached for it to work. FragmentActivity where used pre- honeycomb. Honeycomb above require an activity

Comment: Better yet, create a Toolbar layouts folder, and use <include> tag to include it everywhere you use it to minimize code usage. This assumes you have the same toolbar in every fragment / activity

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>

Comment: wasnt u able to add toolbar by using this

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated and in FragmentActivity there is no getActivity method

Comment: Please ignore this, it's not correct. as of 2019. You have to use AppCompactActivity.

Answer (score 3):

You should extend your Activity from AppCompatActivity as this includes support for Fragments and the Toolbar

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { ...

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ....
    ....
```