# Trying to make Toolbar work with Fragment Activity. Any ideas?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-fragmentactivity

I am using fragmentActivity, and it already extends OnMapReadyCallback, and cannot extend activity or appcompat.

THis gives me error on setSupportActionBar.

Java :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
 OnMapReadyCallback 

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This is the error that comes up - Error:(80, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)

Activity Layout:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pos.gisapp.MapsActivity" />
```

And the actual app_bar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: What's the error telling you that you are not able to extend to AppCompatActivity?

Comment: You can extend [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html), which in turn extends (support) FragmentActivity.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148276/adding-toolbar-to-a-fragmentactivity

Comment: Ok i Extended AppCompatActivity, and it all works no errors. Now the bar doesn show when i run app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of the support library, you should make your `Activity` extend `AppCompatActivity`

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: Got that also. Now the error is gone. But the bar is not showing, when i run the app

Comment: what about toolbar height

Comment: Toolbar height is set to wrap_content

Comment: So i noticed carefully...the app runs..the toolbar shows, then disappears and the tile overlay i am pulling comes over it.

Comment: so please set height 50 dp and check

Comment: i tried that. It still disappears. Elevation also set to 5dp. Not that i have a clue about that

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: Thats toolbar.xml